# What does K3Fe(CN)6 become?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions

What does the salt $\ce{K3Fe(CN)6}$ change to when it is dissolved in water? I mean, I think its going to ionize, but in what way? Is there a way to know this? I tried to search the web but wasn't able to find the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In water it should dissociate into $\ce{K+}$ and $\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^3-}$. This is because the $\ce{Fe}$ forms an octahedral complex with $\ce{Fe}$ at the centre and six $\ce{CN-}$ ions distributed around this each at 90 degrees to one another. This ion is sufficiently stable that it will not dissociate in water. The bonding is due to $\mathrm d$ orbitals on the $\ce{Fe}$. All undergraduate inorganic text books will give details of this. The Wikipedia page on [ferricyanide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferricyanide) gives pictures of the complex's geometry.